# Is there a way to run a .net exe on heroku?

Tags: .net, node.js, heroku, exe

I've wondered if there is a way to run a .net executable file in heroku.I know heroku is linux based but is there some way?

Here is my test code that works on my computer (Windows).
The exe file writes in "writetext.txt" and then i read it.

```html
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 1234;
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
var fs = require('fs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"))

var server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(port);
app.get('/exec', function(req, res){
 exec('Test.exe', function(err, data) {  
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString() + "data");                     
    });
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/writetext.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(data);
    res.end(data.toString());
 });
});
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
 res.send("Hello word!");
 res.end();
});
console.log("http server listening on %d", port)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly a way to run .NET code on Linux (or MacOS). You will want to use Mono (http://www.mono-project.com/). Essentially Mono is an open source implementation of CLR among other portions of .NET. After installing mono, instead of running Test.exe you would run mono with Test.exe as a parameter. It is really straightforward. I would install Mono for your platform and just try running your test executable from the command line '`mono ./Test.exe`' to start. If that looks good you can update your node app to run with mono or create a script that does essentially the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! But i want to run it not on my linux machine but on heroku.

Comment: I see. I looked into it and I do not see that they have a standard shell, my mistake.